# Vue JS: Join a v-bind and a v-if in one div?

Tags: vue.js

Is there any way I can join these two together so they are both on the div?

```
<div
      :class="
        Date.now() >= new Date(deadline)
          ? 'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container hideclosed'
          : 'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container'
      "
    >
      <h3 v-bind:class="{ showclosed: $store.state.ClassCheck }">
        {{title }}
      </h3>
```

Comment: technically you can but if you're doing something with classes or performing an animations you might want to consider using <Transition/>

Comment: `:class="{Date.now() >= new Date(deadline) ? 'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container hideclosed' : 'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container', showclosed: $store.state.ClassCheck}"`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't get this to work. It displayed an error at Date.now() for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) can be used in class bindings to conditionally apply multiple class names.

For example, the following binding applies the `active` class when `isActive` is `true`, and unconditionally applies the class name from the `errorClass` prop:

```html
<div :class="[{ active: isActive }, errorClass]"></div>
```

In your case, the two class bindings would be combined in an array:

```html
<div
      :class="[
        Date.now() >= new Date(deadline)
          ? 'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container hideclosed'
          : 'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container',

        { showclosed: $store.state.ClassCheck }
      ]"
    >
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QWpGowg)

To improve template readability, use a computed prop to contain the complex array:

```html
<div :class="myClasses">
```

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    myClasses() {
      return [
        Date.now() >= new Date(this.deadline)
          ? 'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container hideclosed'
          : 'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container',

        { showclosed: this.$store.state.ClassCheck },
      ]

      // OR simplified:
      return [
        'search-result col-12 col-lg-10 container',
        { hideclosed: Date.now() >= new Date(this.deadline) },
        { showclosed: this.$store.state.ClassCheck },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/BaWQbNL)